# Socket error 's' not defined

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

I am trying to make a graphical chatroom in python socket/tkinter but I get an error

Full Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Theta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\CODEDRIVE_BACKUP\PyTkinter\1.2.py", line 19, in f
    s.send(q)
NameError: name 's' is not defined
```

Here is host code:

```
from tkinter import *
import socket, time


tk = Tk()

def c():
    d = a.get()
    print('[LOG] NOW HOSTING ' + d)
    HOST = d               # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
    PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        s.listen(10)
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            print('Connected by', addr)
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
                data = conn.recv(1024)

a = Entry(tk, width=55, bg='light green')
a.grid(row=1, column=1)
b = Button(tk, width=55, text="HOST", command=c)
b.grid(row=2, column=1)


tk.mainloop()
```

Client Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import socket
import socket

tk = Tk()

def c():
    d = a.get()
    HOST = d    # The remote host
    PORT = 50007              # The same port as used by the server
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((HOST, PORT))
def f():
        q = open('SEND.txt', 'rb')


        s.send(q)
        data = s.recv(1024)

a = Entry(tk, width=55, bg='light green')
a.grid(row=1, column=1)
b = Button(tk, width=55, text="CONNECT", command=c)
b.grid(row=2, column=1)
c = Button(tk, width=55, text="SEND", command =f)
c.grid(row=3, column=1)


tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Under `def f():`... What is `s`?? Your error is not lying

Comment: That error message is pretty clear: you never defined "s", so `s.send(q)` makes no sense.

Comment: variables can also be more than single letters. Please try to make your code understandable for others

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the client code.

You've defined `s` in function `c()`, that means that it's a local variable, thus, you cannot access it outside of `c()`

Also, when you're trying to change your code to solve the problem, keep in mind that if you open your socket with the `with`statement(which is what you did in function `c()`), it would only be usable inside that block of code(the `with` block).